# Render view inside iframe in Angular 6 and continue to use template variables

Tags: typescript, iframe, angular6

In angularJS, you could use $compile to render a view in an iframe as well as keep the angularjs $scope variables within the iframe. Is there an equivalent functionality in Angular.IO?

AngularJS equivalent in a directive:

```
var $body = angular.element($element[0].contentDocument.body);
var template = $compile(contents)($scope);
$body.append(template);
```

I would like to render an iframe, pass the necessary html to populate the iframe and be able to use the template language inside the iframe html.

Similar to this but, [this plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/CoFXp3/) isn't working. It doesn't render the variables in the iframe view.

Update: Found some tutorials on how to use angularJS in typescript and that might work. Ultimately, I would like to share variables between the parent and iframe, similar to how $scope in angularJS can be shared between parent and iframe.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get the iframe `Window` and inject a variable from the Angular component, you might to inject a `Subject` so you can trigger changes ([**FULL DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4nkntw)) inside the iframe like this:

Here is the template component

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<button (click)="sendData()">Click Here</button>
<iframe #iframe frameborder="1" width="100%" height="50%"></iframe>
```

And here is the logic:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

const iframeCode = `
  <h1>Hello World</h1>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    if (dataFromParent) {
      // Subscribe to the Subject so you can trigger changes from Angular
      dataFromParent.subscribe(res => {
        document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = res;
      })
    }
  </script>
`

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  data$: Subject<string> = new Subject('');
  @ViewChild('iframe') iframe: ElementRef;

  name = 'Angular';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setIframeReady(this.iframe);
  }

  sendData() {
    this.data$.next('From parent to iframe');
  }

  private setIframeReady(iframe: ElementRef): void {
    const win: Window = iframe.nativeElement.contentWindow;

    // Pass the variable from parent to iframe
    win['dataFromParent'] = this.data$;

    const doc: Document = win.document;
    doc.open();
    doc.write(iframeCode);
    doc.close()
  }
}
```

Also, if you want to communicate from iframe to parent you could use [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent).

Hope it help.

Comment: You're awesome @fmontes - Works perfectly

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Comment: Here is the plunkr modified to use the CustomEvent (with IE polyfill); to send data back to parent. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fwipyk.

Comment: Hey Tim, sorry I didn't respond earlier I was AFK all weekend. Awesome you made it work.

Comment: No problem @fmontes, I figure it was a tough ask over the weekend. Did get it working, thanks again.

Comment: Hello,
this.data$.next('From parent to iframe'); is not working in IE 11.

Comment: @Potinos I don't have a way to test it right now but, can you tell me what error you're getting?

Comment: @fmontes, there's no error but dataFromParent is never true.
Iframe is not updated.
Thank you for this helpfull post :)

Comment: Or may be win['dataFromParent'] is not a valid declaration of variable in IE.

Comment: @Potinos it should be. If you `console.log(window)` before the `if` can you inspect if you get the property?

Comment: @Deb glad to hear

Comment: Thanks @fmontes, thank you very very much, i was stuck for 3-4 days on same page but your solution has solved my problem.

Comment: @SanjayTiwari glad it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I am facing similar situation but i have to load another angular app APP2 from inside APP1.